# How to rise PropertyChanged event without passing property name as a string?

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

In wpf we often use following pattern for bindable properties:

```
private Foo _bar = new Foo();
public Foo Bar
{
    get { return _bar; }
    set
    {
        _bar = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string property = "")
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
}
```

[`CallerMemberNameAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute.aspx) does nice magic, generating for us `"Bar"` parameter from setter name.

However, often there are properties without setter or dependent properties:

```
private Foo _bar;
public Foo Bar
{
    get { return _bar; }
    set
    {
        _bar = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

public bool IsBarNull
{
    get { return _bar == null; }
}
```

In given example, when `Bar` is changed then `IsBarNull` needs event too. We can add `OnPropertyChanged("IsBarNull");` into `Bar` setters, but ... using `string` for properties is:

- ugly;
- hard to refactor (VS's "Rename" will not rename property name in `string`);
- can be a source of all kind of mistakes.

WPF exists for so long. Is there no *magical* solution yet (similar to `CallerMemberNameAttribute`)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use C# 6 and the [`nameof`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596(v=vs.140).aspx) feature:

```
OnPropertyChange(nameof(IsBarNull));
```

That generates equivalent code to:

```
OnPropertyChange("IsBarNull");
```

... but without the fragility.

If you're stuck on earlier versions of C#, you *can* use expression trees for this, but I regard that as a bit of a hack and a potential performance issue (as the tree is recreated on each call). `nameof` doesn't require any library support, just a new compiler - so if you upgrade to VS 2015 (or later, dear readers from the future...) you should be fine.

Comment: Here it is a good example in C# 5 using lambda expressions. Unfortunately this is not an efficient solution, but encountered in applications.  -   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7728465/implementing-notifypropertychanged-without-magic-strings

Comment: @PawelMaga: Which were you thinking of? I can't see any examples using reflection there. Are you thinking of expression trees?

Comment: Sees hot question. "Hey Jon Skeet's video showed me how to do that with C# 6!". Jon Skeet has already answered...

Answer (score 1):

if C# 6 is not at hand, here's some method i'm using quite often using Expressions:

```
public static class ExpressionExtensions
{
    public static string GetMemberName<T>(this Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
    {
        return GetMemberName(expression.Body);
    }

    public static string GetMemberName (this Expression propertyExpression)
    {
        var lambda = propertyExpression as LambdaExpression;
        MemberExpression memberExpression = null;

        if (propertyExpression is UnaryExpression)
        {
            var unaryExpression = propertyExpression as UnaryExpression;
            memberExpression = unaryExpression.Operand as MemberExpression;
        }
        else if (lambda != null && lambda.Body is UnaryExpression)
        {
            var unaryExpression = lambda.Body as UnaryExpression;
            memberExpression = unaryExpression.Operand as MemberExpression;
        }
        else if (lambda != null)
        {
            memberExpression = lambda.Body as MemberExpression;
        }
        else
        {
            var expression = propertyExpression as MemberExpression;
            if (expression != null)
                memberExpression = expression;
        }

        if (memberExpression == null) return null;

        var propertyInfo = memberExpression.Member;

        return propertyInfo.Name;
    }
}
```

usage:

```
var propertyName = ExpressionExtensions.GetMemberName<DateTime>(item => item.Day);
```

Answer (score 0):

DevExpress offers in it's `BindableBase` class a method `SetProperty` which reflects on the property you like to set:

```
private Foo _bar;
public Foo Bar
{
    get { return _bar; }
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref _bar, value, () => Bar);
    }
}
```

It automatically looks for the correct property to update and only sends property changed events if necessary