# how to move from one tabitem to another in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, ado.net, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I have a `tab-control` with three tab items. each tab item has a `datagrid` placed on it.
and all these three datagrid's on their respective tab items is of Master-Detail-SubDetail form.

how to move from first tab item to the second tab item when a user selects a row on the Master datagrid? I have created a Model using `ADO.Net` entity framework to create this master-detail view.

XAML layout

```
 <TabControl Height="270" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="16,23,0,0" Name="tabControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="462">
        <TabItem Header="Person" Name="tabItem1">
            <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource peopleViewSource}">
                <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" Height="166" SelectedItem="{Binding personDetails}"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="64,23,0,0" Name="peopleDataGrid" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="289">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="personIDColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=personID}" Header="person ID" Width="SizeToHeader" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="firstNameColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=firstName}" Header="first Name" Width="SizeToHeader" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="lastNameColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=lastName}" Header="last Name" Width="SizeToHeader" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Person Details" Name="tabItem2">
            <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource peoplepersonDetailsViewSource}">
                <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" Height="120" SelectedItem="{Binding personDetails.personStatus}"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="82,18,0,0" Name="personDetailsDataGrid" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="172">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="detailIDColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=detailID}" Header="detail ID" Width="SizeToHeader" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="positionColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=position}" Header="position" Width="SizeToHeader" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="personIDColumn1" Binding="{Binding Path=personID}" Header="person ID" Width="SizeToHeader" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Person Status" Name="tabItem3">
            <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource peoplepersonDetailspersonStatusViewSource}">
                <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" Height="143" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="91,23,0,0" Name="personStatusDataGrid" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="185">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="detailIDColumn1" Binding="{Binding Path=detailID}" Header="detail ID" Width="SizeToHeader" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="positionColumn1" Binding="{Binding Path=position}" Header="position" Width="SizeToHeader" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="statussColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=statuss}" Header="statuss" Width="SizeToHeader" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

[image: tab item 1]

[image: tab item 2]

Comment: I sense a complete lack of MVVM here...

Comment: look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209870/dynamically-updating-tabcontrol-content-at-runtime/15210593#15210593) explanation of what a `TabControl` really is...

Comment: There's no WPF without MVVM... you're gonna suffer a LOT if you try to use WPF in a winforms way.

Comment: Thanks for the link, i just started my app by generating entities.

Comment: You could use a `DataTrigger` on the Master `Datagrid` to set the `TabControls` `SelectedIndex`

Comment: can you pls provide an example? thanks

Comment: Its a bit hard without knowing your xaml layout

Comment: kindly see my edited questions for the screenshots and xaml layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could setup a `EventTrigger` on the `DataGrid` `SelectionChanged` event

Because EventTrigger only allowa Animation you can setup a `Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames` animation to change the `TabControl` `SelectedIndex`

Trigger

```
 <DataGrid.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="DataGrid.SelectionChanged" > // SelectionChanged Event
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard >
                <Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="tabControl1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="SelectedIndex"> // set target control and target property
                    <SplineInt32KeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1"/> // Value = TabControl Selected index you want to show
                </Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</DataGrid.Triggers>
```

Here is an example:

```
<TabControl Height="270" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="16,23,0,0" Name="tabControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="462">
        <TabItem Header="Person" Name="tabItem1">
            <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource peopleViewSource}">
                <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" Height="166" SelectedItem="{Binding personDetails}"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="64,23,0,0" Name="peopleDataGrid" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="289">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="personIDColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=personID}" Header="person ID" Width="SizeToHeader" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="firstNameColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=firstName}" Header="first Name" Width="SizeToHeader" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="lastNameColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=lastName}" Header="last Name" Width="SizeToHeader" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGrid.Triggers>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="DataGrid.SelectionChanged" >
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard >
                                        <Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="tabControl1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="SelectedIndex">
                                            <SplineInt32KeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1"/>
                                        </Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger>
                        </DataGrid.Triggers>
                </DataGrid>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
     ......
```

Here is my mockup

Code:

```
namespace WpfApplication7
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        private Person _selectedPerson;
        private ObservableCollection<Person> _persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Items.Add(new Person { personID = "Stack" });
            Items.Add(new Person { personID = "Overflow" });
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Person> Items
        {
            get { return _persons; }
            set { _persons = value; }
        }

        public Person SelectedPerson
        {
            get { return _selectedPerson; }
            set { _selectedPerson = value; }
        }

    }

    public class Person
    {
        public string personID { get; set; }
        public string firstname { get; set; }
        public string lastname { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication7.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="399" Width="464" Name="UI" >

    <Grid>
        <TabControl Height="270" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="16,23,0,0" Name="tabControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="462">
            <TabItem Header="Person" Name="tabItem1">
                <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UI, Path=Items}" >
                    <DataGrid  AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" Height="166" SelectedItem="{Binding personDetails}"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="64,23,0,0" Name="peopleDataGrid" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="289">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="personIDColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=personID}" Header="person ID" Width="SizeToHeader" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="firstNameColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=firstName}" Header="first Name" Width="SizeToHeader" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="lastNameColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=lastName}" Header="last Name" Width="SizeToHeader" />
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGrid.Triggers>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="DataGrid.SelectionChanged" >
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard >
                                        <Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="tabControl1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="SelectedIndex">
                                            <SplineInt32KeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1"/>
                                        </Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger>
                        </DataGrid.Triggers>
                    </DataGrid>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Person Details" Name="tabItem2">
                <Grid>
                    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" Height="120" SelectedItem="{Binding personDetails.personStatus}"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="82,18,0,0" Name="personDetailsDataGrid" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="172">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="detailIDColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=detailID}" Header="detail ID" Width="SizeToHeader" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="positionColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=position}" Header="position" Width="SizeToHeader" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="personIDColumn1" Binding="{Binding Path=personID}" Header="person ID" Width="SizeToHeader" />
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Person Status" Name="tabItem3">
                <Grid>
                    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" Height="143" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="91,23,0,0" Name="personStatusDataGrid" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="185">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="detailIDColumn1" Binding="{Binding Path=detailID}" Header="detail ID" Width="SizeToHeader" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="positionColumn1" Binding="{Binding Path=position}" Header="position" Width="SizeToHeader" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="statussColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=statuss}" Header="statuss" Width="SizeToHeader" />
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. but i have an error saying- "An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: Specified cast is not valid."

Comment: It works fine here, I have added the mockup app I used to test this `Trigger` so you can test outside of your application

Comment: ok. thanks indeed :) just one more question, doesn't it have a code behind for the routedevent ?

Comment: No there is no need for code behind of the event as we are using it as a trigger

Comment: This works perfect for me , but if I select my first tabitem, I get an exception as "System.InvalidCastException"- {"Specified cast is not valid."}.. pls can you help me to solve this issue. I am stuck here :( Thanks indeed