# MenuItem with dynamic MenuItems

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have this `MenuBar` in my application:

```
<Menu Grid.Row="0" Height="22" Name="menu1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
        <MenuItem Header="File" />
        <MenuItem Header="Youtube">

        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Help" />
    </Menu>
```

And i want to add items to the Youtube `MenuItem` dynamic ,something like this:

```
MenuItem menu = (MenuItem)sender;
        ItemCollection items = menu.Items;
        items.Clear();

        if (YouTubeAuth.CreateInstance().IsLogin())
        {
            MenuItem refreshItem = new MenuItem();
            refreshItem.Header = "Refresh";
            refreshItem.Click += DidPressRefresh;
            items.Add(refreshItem);

            MenuItem logouttItem = new MenuItem();
            logouttItem.Header = "Signout";
            logouttItem.Click += DidPressLogout;
            items.Add(logouttItem);
        }
        else
        {
            MenuItem loginItem = new MenuItem();
            loginItem.Header = "Login";
            loginItem.Click += DidPressLogin;
            items.Add(loginItem);
        }
```

It say if you login show logout and refresh otherwise shot login.
I try to add this method to `Click="DidPressDeleteAllFavorites"` of the `Youtube MenuItem` but it won't work.
Any idea how to fix it? what i do wrong?

Comment: What did not work? Do you receive an error? Have you debugged your code?

Comment: In the first time i clicked the YouTube MenuItem nothing happen(But this method call), and from there any time i clicked the YouTube MenuItem the MenuItem is open

Comment: Is the second part of your code an event-handler?

Comment: You shouldn't be creating parts of the UI in procedural code. You have to bind these `Menu`s to `Lists` of `ICommand`s. Please look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209870/dynamically-updating-tabcontrol-content-at-runtime/15210593#15210593) explanation of what a `Menu` really is.

Comment: I try to bind it but i want that every time the MenuItem is click it will Bind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using the MVVM-pattern

```
<MenuItem Header="Youtube" ItemsSource="{Binding yourProperty}"/>
```

---

if you are working with code-behind

XAML

```
 <MenuItem Header="Youtube" Name="myYoutube"/>
```

Code-behind

```
 myYoutube.ItemsSource=yourMenuItems;
```

---

### EDIT

the problem in your code is in my opinion you just need to call your Event Code on on startup because your Youtube has no subMenuitem on begin or you could also call `UpdateLayout()` in your event this could also maybe fix it

### Working Example

**Codebehind**

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        bool test = false;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MenuItem_Click(myYouTube, null);
        }

        private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var mymenuitem = sender as MenuItem;

            MenuItem menu = (MenuItem)sender;
            ItemCollection items = menu.Items;
            items.Clear();

            if (test)
            {
                MenuItem refreshItem = new MenuItem();
                refreshItem.Header = "Refresh";
                //refreshItem.Click += DidPressRefresh;
                items.Add(refreshItem);

                MenuItem logouttItem = new MenuItem();
                logouttItem.Header = "Signout";
                //logouttItem.Click += DidPressLogout;
                items.Add(logouttItem);


                test = false;
            }
            else
            {
                MenuItem loginItem = new MenuItem();
                loginItem.Header = "Login";
                //loginItem.Click += DidPressLogin;
                items.Add(loginItem);

                test = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

**XAML**

```
 <Menu Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="84,66,0,0" Name="menu1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200">
            <MenuItem Header="File" />
            <MenuItem Header="Youtube" Name="myYouTube" Click="MenuItem_Click">

            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Help" />
        </Menu>
```

Comment: This is what i do in the Click Event but in the first time i click the menu won't open

Comment: i will edit my answer because i thing in know now whats wrong ^^

Comment: I noticed that when i add with Menu item to myYoutube the Click event won't called

Comment: and this method called in your code every time you click myYouTube MenuItem?

Comment: `private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)` is called everytime you clicked on a child item like `Login`

Comment: sry but i don't understand your actually problem. Because i thing it fit's your needs  or i'm wrong?

Comment: From what i understant the click event won't called after i add menu item to menuitem

Comment: did you add ` Click="MenuItem_Click"` in your XAML?  because in my case it works like i think you need it. `onStartup` and after each `Click` on your `MenuItemChilds` (`Refresh`,`Signout`,`Login`) if you click on `Youtube` nothing will happend what else do you need?

Comment: by the way i don't know why `MenuItem_Click` won't get called if you click on just on `Youtube` and not on a `Child`

Comment: Thanks for the help, i used your post to achieve my goal