# Access CustomControl's element programmatically in WPF

Tags: wpf, user-controls, custom-controls, apply-templates

I have created a custom control which will have only one Grid into it.

Here is the part of the code from `Generic.xaml`

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MainView}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MainView }">
                    <Grid x:Name="**PART_MyGrid**" Background="Black" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
              Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
 </Style>
```

Corresponding `MainView.cs` is as follows:

```
[TemplatePart(Name = "PART_MyGrid", Type = typeof(Grid))]
    public class MainView : ContentControl
    {
        private Grid MainViewGrid;
        static MainView()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MainView), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MainView)));
        }
        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            //This Function never gets called
            base.OnApplyTemplate();

            //Find the grid in the template once it's applied
            MainViewGrid = base.Template.FindName("**PART_MyGrid**", this) as Grid;
            //We can subscribe to its events
        }
        public void setGrid(DataGrid dtGrid)
        {
***//Exception saying MainViewGrid is null***
            MainViewGrid.Children.Add(dtGrid);
        }
    }
```

Now I have created a another project and I want to include this custom control into one of the panel programmatically.

This is what I have done in .cs file from different project , where I wanted to create this CustomControl dynamically.

```
CustomControlLib.MainView m_View = new CustomControlLib.MainView();

***//... Code to create One Datagrid programmatically ...***
   m_View.setGrid(programmatically_created_dataGrid);
   theTabItem.Content = m_View;
   theTabItem.DataContext = m_View.DataContext;
```

What exactly I want is , I want to create `CustomControl` dynamically and then add it to `TabItem`.
So, I want to access `Grid` in `CustomControl` and add `DataGrid` to it programmatically.
But `OnApplyTemplate()` gets called only when the Custom control is displayed in the screen.
In my case its giving exception saying `"MainViewGrid is null"`
So, how do I access MainView CustomControl's element in this case or rather call `OnApplyTemplate()`, so that I can "find" Grid and add DataGrid to it.

Comment: Please learn MVVM before you ever write a single line of code in WPF. Also, what you're doing here looks more like a `UserControl`, not a Custom Control. See [MSDN - Control Authoring Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Iam a bit new to WPF , hence I dont know anything from MVVM perspective. I'll surely try and learn MVVM. But from above code,Iam just not getting the way to create CustomControl programmatically, so that I can access CustomControl's Element in cs file. If you could help, that wud be ideal.

Comment: you do NOT need a Custom Control at all. and no you do NOT create or manipulate UI elements in procedural code in WPF. That's what XAML is for. See [How to properly create a dynamically defined TabControl in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15210593/643085)

Comment: But I want to add a datagrid programmatically into CustomControl/UserControl as a child of CC's Grid. So, I dont know how to do it using XAML.

Comment: have you read the link I posted?

Comment: I read the link , but that is more from MVVM perspective. Cant I get the solution without MVVM

Comment: no you cannot work in WPF without using proper DataBinding and Data Templating.