# Can I write the method name without using a String to pass the name of the method? (c#)

Tags: c#

I have got this class:

```
class foo
{
   int val;
   public int Val
   {
      set{ val = values; },
      set{ val = values; }
   }
}
```

I need to pass the property name to a DataBinding:

```
String propertyName = "Val";
ctrl.DataBindings.Add(propertyName, object, dataMember, true, DataSourceUpdateMode.Never);
```

I want to do something like this:

```
propertyName = typeof(foo).methods.Val.toString();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can use C#6, you have the `nameof` operator, which does just that.

```
string propertyName = nameof(foo.Val);
```

If you use C# 5, you can leverage expression trees:

```
public static string GetPropertyName<TParent>(Expression<Func<TParent, object>> prop)
{
    var expr = prop.Body;

    if (expr.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert)
        expr = ((UnaryExpression)expr).Operand;

    if (expr.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
        return ((MemberExpression)expr).Member.Name;

    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid lambda", "prop");
}
```

Use this helper function like this (assuming it's in a `ReflectionHelper` class):

```
string propertyName = ReflectionHelper.GetPropertyName<foo>(x => x.Val);
```

This way, you can safely use refactorings in your IDE.

Comment: Thank you, this solution works on 4.5 .NET. I suppose that with this code the string ofuscation does not break the program.

Comment: @dlopezgonzalez Yes, the expression tree method shouldn't break in this case, as it references the assembly metadata. But the `nameof` method would still break if you change the property name after the build through obfuscation.

Comment: I hope, for example, the old eazfuscator broke the code when reflection was used. To avoid this, I needed to add this add the top of the class "[System.Reflection.ObfuscationAttribute(Feature = "properties renaming", Exclude = true)]". I hope this helps to another one leaving this here.

Answer (score 1):

As of C# 6, you can use the `nameof` operator:

```
ctrl.DataBindings.Add(nameof(foo.Val), /* other arguments as before */);
```

Before C# 6, there's no really simple way to do this at compile-time. One option, however, is to have unit tests which check that all your property names are actual properties (checking with reflection).

Also note that in C# 5 there's [`CallerMemberNameAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is useful for implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` - but isn't as useful for your case.

The approach of using expression trees works, but it feels somewhat clunky to me. Although far lower tech, simple string constants and a unit test feels a bit simpler.

Comment: Most MVVM frameworks (actually the parts that implement INotifyPropertyChanged) work by passing expressions that point to the properties. No need for reflection

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: The reflection I'm suggesting would be entirely at *test* time.

Comment: This sounds weird too - using tests for static analysis. Almost sounds like a Roslyn diagnostic :).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I'm already planning on converting some Noda Time unit tests into diagnostics :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using C# 6, you need to pass around an `Expression<Func<T>>`.

You can then do this with that object (if you are passing a property):

```
 private string GetPropertyName(Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpession)
 {
   //the cast will always succeed if properly used
   MemberExpression memberExpression = (MemberExpression)propertyExpression.Body;
   string propertyName = memberExpression.Member.Name;
   return propertyName;
 }
```

You would use this like:

```
var propName = GetPropertyName(() => this.Val);
```

Comment: Note that you don't want to be doing that too often, however - I don't *think* expression trees are cached.

Comment: I checked and you're right they're not. This is almost word for word the same code as used by PRISM's `OnPropertyChanged()` implementation tho' - so it can't be that bad, right? ;)

Comment: @JonSkeet most MVVM frameworks use that trick for INotifyPropertyChanged implementations, although the final code has to be a lot more robust.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: That doesn't mean it's necessarily a good idea - and in fact in C# 5 you'd want to use `CallerMemberNameAttribute` for `INotifyPropertyChanged` anyway.

Comment: A framework can add its own caching. The leading frameworks have no performance problems so either they do cache, or the problem isn't so significant *in this scenario*. CallerMemberNameAttribute is restricted to passing the caller's name only so you can't update related properties. Only `nameof` is a full alternative

Comment: @JonSkeet: That's very interesting because PRISM 5.0 is in .NET 4.5 and doesn't use `CallerMemberName` for `INotifyPropertyChanged` in `BindableBase`. It's also supposed to be the embodiment of best practice... Is it an oversight, do you think?

Comment: Best practices aren't always universally agreed on :) I'd have to look carefully at the code to see whether it would be suitable.

Comment: @toadflakz PRISM isn't exactly regarded as best-practice - actually it's considered to be over-overengineered, infrequently updated and its View-first approach makes implementing MVVM harder. The major MVVM frameworks like MVVM Light or Caliburn.Micro *do* use expressions and CallerMemberName

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're using INotifyPropertyChanged but there's some articles on how to avoid using "magic strings" here which may be of use:

[Implementing NotifyPropertyChanged without magic strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7728465/implementing-notifypropertychanged-without-magic-strings)

[typesafe NotifyPropertyChanged using linq expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711435/typesafe-notifypropertychanged-using-linq-expressions)

Answer (score 0):

Check out statically typed reflection with LINQ: http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/kzu/statically-typed-reflection-with-linq/

You can do:

```
string propertyName = Reflect<foo>.GetProperty(x => x.Val).Name;
```

Comment: That's still reflection, and it isn't needed if you can just pass an expression with the property